# Is Neo-Vedanta a sect of Hinduism?

Tags: vedanta, neo-vedanta

Is [Neo-Vedanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Vedanta) a sect of Hinduism?

This wikipedia article says this:

> Neo-Vedanta..... are terms to characterize interpretations of Hinduism
>   that developed in the 19th century. Some scholars argue that these
>   modern interpretations incorporate western ideas[4] into traditional
>   Indian religions, especially Advaita Vedanta, which is asserted as
>   central or fundamental to Hindu culture.[5]

And then it says:

> **Although neo-Vedanta proper developed in the 19th century in response
>   to western colonialism**, it has got deeper origins in the Muslim period
>   of India.[7]

So, Neo-Vedanta seems to be a de-facto sect of Hinduism.

Comment: again, 'Neo-Vedantism' is a term coined by Western scholars that is meant to demean Hinduism and Hindu beliefs. There are no sects or schools of Neo-Vedantists...

Comment: A sect has to start from God. You urself say tht Neo-V was developed very recently by some human beings... Thn how can it be a sect?

Comment: It's not a sect, it's a label used by Westerners and some Advaitins on Vivekananda's followers.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda So then what would you call those teachings?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda it would be useful if you write an answer to explain. I found [this article](http://www.advaita.org.uk/discourses/trad_neo/neo_vedanta_swartz.htm) is somewhat helpful.